# Tensorflow CNN filters really detect contrast in images with big white zones?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm having problems to understand how a CNN filter is able to give a higher value to perfect fit patchs when you have grayscale images with big white zones.

For example, imagine that I have the next 3x3 filter:

```
0-1-0
0-1-0
0-1-0
```

And this filter is applied to one image with big completely white zones. For example, I could to have a patch of that image, like this:

```
255-255-255
255-255-255
255-255-255
```

and for this patch, the kernel would return (0*255 + 0*255 + 0*255) + (1*255 + 1*255 + 1*255) + (0*255 + 0*255 + 0*255) = 765

and if I apply the same filter to this patch image:

```
0-255-0
0-255-0
0-255-0
```

I would get the same value: (0*0 + 0*0 + 0*0) + (1*255 + 1*255 + 1*255) + (0*0 + 0*0 + 0*0) = 765

But the last one image patch should have got a much better value for kernel, so I am going crazy to understand how this works really

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a few days thinking about it, I have found the answer to my question, using negative values in kernel. After see so many kernel examples with 1's and 0's, I didn't think that the values could to be negatives too.